# Italian consulate Schengen visa time

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, california, consulates

We are planning for a trip to Italy in September. I checked the Italian consulate in San Francisco for visa appointment, but the available dates are in August. Would that be a good option to wait till August for the appointment?

I am not a US citizen and I am traveling to Italy for 9 days.

Also would I need to book a separate appointment for my wife too? Or can we both go for the same appointment time?

Comment: They are supposed to be quicker than that but what's your alternative? Unfortunately, the rules do not allow you to pick another consulate even if they are not very helpful. Also, assuming you can book an appointment for the two of you sounds like a bad idea, definitely do check with them if that's possible and book appointment(s) as soon as possible. If you can't get an answer, I would book two appointments just in case.

Comment: my alternative can be book few days of hotel in some other Schengen country, make an appointment at that consulate and then cancel that hotel booking. Not sure if that is a good idea though

Comment: This other country has to become your main destination and you could still run into problems if you show up at the Italian border with no credible plan to actually go there but if you are willing to change your trip, it's certainly a good solution. Note that if your application is complete, Schengen visa are often issued in a week or two so it's still perfectly possible to make it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we completed our trip. The Italian embassy requires that we book different appointment for all the family members traveling.  Also they do mention the documents they require in a specific Order which greatly reduces the time.

The only issue with the consulate in SFO was that they allot one half-hour slot per appointment and there is only one lady who looks at the applications. Its really a pain but thankfully we did not get any problems with that.

Comment: HI Akshat, I am trying to find more information on the docs needed and how  to apply for Schengen VISA in Italian consulate in SF - but unable to find any proper links. Their website is in all Italian making it even harder. Any links/pointers. Thanks.

Comment: try this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uxGVi_Iy0-MHWoDdhjf7QRJ-ijScmDs429R3lt_Q4iw/edit?usp=sharing    This is what i had saved. Hope this helps